# Scroll Bar Interference with Scroll Snap on Mobile Devices

Tags: html, css, reactjs, mobile-website

I am developing a one-page website that incorporates scroll snap functionality. The website includes a fixed top navigation bar, which I account for in my body components using a fixed top padding. To hide the scroll bar, I have added the following CSS code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

On desktop devices, the scroll snap feature works perfectly, and the scroll bar does not appear randomly when interacting with the navigation bar. However, on mobile devices, a scroll bar appears when interacting with various parts of the screen, including the navigation bar. The scroll bar only allows scrolling within the visible body element, preventing access to the other sections. This interference disrupts the snap-align start requirement of the scroll snap feature. Currently, the issue can only be resolved by waiting for the scroll bar to disappear on its own or by refreshing the page.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to address this issue in my code. Is there a way to prevent the scroll bar from appearing when interacting with the navigation bar and other parts of the screen on mobile devices?

[the screen normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAqtO.png)
[scroll as a result of interacting w/ nav bar, offsets snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGghy.png)

relevant CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

.snap-y-dir {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.screen {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.bluebackground {
  background: blue;
}

.greenbackground {
  background: green;
}

body {
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}
```

js body:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const ref1 = useRef(null);
  const ref2 = useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="flex justify-between">
          <div className="flex justify-between gap-4">
            <li>
              <a href="#blah1">blah1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#blah2">blah2</a>
            </li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <main className="snap-y-dir">
        {/* About Section */}
        <section
          ref={ref1}
          id="blah1"
          className="screen bluebackground"
          style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}
        >
          hello
        </section>

        <section
          ref={ref2}
          id="blah2"
          className="screen greenbackground"
          style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}
        >
          hello
        </section>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's it on the codedamn playground: https://codedamn.com/playground/pmmJMMoPLhvGN4BouMcSh

let me know if the link is faulty!